# copy the line containing single word and paste it to below lines?

Tags: bash, awk, sed

please look below example for details, where mutiple word is pasted with single line word

```
word1
multiple word hello hi
multiple word hi bye
multiple word ok done
word2
multiple word ok bye
multiple word sldfjkdfs sd f
word3
multiple word
```

needed as

```
word1 multiple word hello hi
word1 multiple word hi bye
word1 multiple word ok done
word2 multiple word djsfsj sd fafd
word2 multiple word sldfjkdfs sd f
word3 multiple word
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cat file
#=> word1
#=> multiple word hello hi
#=> multiple word hi bye
#=> multiple word ok done
#=> word2
#=> multiple word ok bye
#=> multiple word sldfjkdfs sd f
#=> word3
#=> multiple word
```

`awk` solution:

```
awk 'NF==1{lastword=$1}NF>1{print lastword,$0}' file
#=> word1 multiple word hello hi
#=> word1 multiple word hi bye
#=> word1 multiple word ok done
#=> word2 multiple word ok bye
#=> word2 multiple word sldfjkdfs sd f
#=> word3 multiple word
```

`NF` represents the column numbers (the words number here),
`lastword` to save the single word.
`NF>1` means there are multiple words.

`sed` solution (GNU sed):

```
sed -nr '/^[^ \t]+$/h;/^[^ \t]+[ \t]+[^ \t]+/{G;s/(.*)\n(.*)/\2 \1/;p}' file
#=> word1 multiple word hello hi
#=> word1 multiple word hi bye
#=> word1 multiple word ok done
#=> word2 multiple word ok bye
#=> word2 multiple word sldfjkdfs sd f
#=> word3 multiple word
```

It used `hold space` to store the single word,
then append to multiple words line and switch.
`h` Overwrite the contents of hold space with pattern space.
`G` Append the contents of hold space to pattern space,
separate them by a newline character.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^\S\+$/h;//d;G;s/\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/\2 \1/' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Perl solution

```
/tmp> cat vgrs.txt
word1
multiple word hello hi
multiple word hi bye
multiple word ok done
word2
multiple word ok bye
multiple word sldfjkdfs sd f
word3
multiple word
/tmp> perl -lne  ' /^(\S+)$/ and $x=$1 ; print "$x $_" if /\s/ ' vgrs.txt
word1 multiple word hello hi
word1 multiple word hi bye
word1 multiple word ok done
word2 multiple word ok bye
word2 multiple word sldfjkdfs sd f
word3 multiple word
/tmp>
```